# transparent proxy to lo

Tags: proxy, iptables, transparent-proxy

I am trying to setup a transparent proxy between eth0 and lo,

The reason being during DNS propagation services are being tunneled over a SSH connection between the old and new servers, on the "old" server this is fine for anything running locally connecting to localhost:

However for anything hitting the external address of the "old server" the service is not forward as the ssh tunnel only listens for connections to localhost (lo).

Current setup:

```
Old server --> SSH Tunnel --> New server
```

What needs to happen

```
Client connection (i.e. tcp 8081) --> Old Server --> SSH Tunnel --> New server
```

I am trying multiple variations on ip table rules, setting `-L <service port>:0.0.0.0:<service port>` does not listen on all interfaces only on lo.

The solution must come from iptables alone, there is no time to deploy squid / another proxy service.

So in summary.

- Assume tcp 8081, is tunneled over SSH connection
- I need this to work from the eth0 bound address

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be getting you wrong. But why don't you just bind the Endpoint of the SSH Tunnel to eth0 and allow the connection from remote hosts with the -g switch.

To quote from the manpage:

> ```
> -g      Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.
> ```

Comment: Certainly "could not see the wood for the trees", thank you!